# How to register a callback to Blazor's js code for startup issues?

Tags: blazor

My Blazor WebAssembly app failed to start on an Android 8 with Chrome. It works on Android 9 with an even older Chrome, so that problem itself has low priority for me.

However, the issue prompted me to want to have an error handler for the Blazor startup: I do have a remote logging target used when Blazor runs fine, but if it can't get up, I won't notice this problem if it happens on a customer's device.

I added a throw directly in `Program.cs` to simulate a startup issue, and this does lead to `blazor-error-ui` being shown, but now I can't find any error callback register functions on the `Blazor` object.

I've tried using the manual startup, hoping that the returned promise give back an error, but this isn't the case:

```js
        Blazor.start().then(
            () => console.info("started just fine"),
            reason => console.info("could not start: " + reason)
        )
```

This gives `started just fine`.

So what can be done here?